# Big matrices in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, signal-processing

Following my previous question in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53248853/access-data-in-different-files-stored-in-different-folders/53249672#53249672):

I'm trying to build a 128 row matrix with N column (up to many millions). The sole purpose of this matrix is to calculate the mean or median of all 128 rows column wise and save it as a vector (same number of columns as my data).

The size of my data files varies a lot and with smaller ones I've been able to perform just this without any issues using the code from the previous post (see above). But of course, if I'm dealing with bigger datasets I run out of memory. Keep in mind that the error is in concatenating the 128 rows into a new matrix.

EDIT the code used for concatenating the data in the files is the following:

```
for k = TTs;   %TTs to plot
    cd (strcat('TT',num2str(k)));   %TT folder

        for w = 1:4;
            load(strcat('TT',num2str(k),'ch',num2str(w),'.mat'));
            allChs1(4*(k-1)+w,:) = data(1,:);   %concatenate into one matrix
        end

    cd ..
end
```

I've considered averaging 128 rows (on a column by column basis) and consecutively save that value, but have been utterly unsuccessful in doing so...

Any idea on how I could implement this? And, might there be a better way of getting the average of 128 rows on column by column basis?

Cheers,
Oiko

Comment: Show what code you've tried, a [MCVE] (using only a small example, we can imagine some bigger input), and point to why it doesn't work.

Comment: @Wolfie thanks, just added the code for the concatenation of data files

Comment: Are you pre-allocating `allChs1`? With the code you show here, it gets re-allocated every time you add a row, meaning you're using way more memory than necessary.

Comment: What is many millions? An 128x10,000,000 matrix of doubles needs less than 10 GB. How much memory do you have available?

Comment: @Cris Luengo In fact I am not preallocating... The size of the matrix is not known before hand and I haven't managed to change the code adequately in order to allocate progressively. Concerning the size of the matrix, it ranges between a few dozens to hundreds of millions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can incrementally compute an average, so that you only have one dataset and the average value in memory:

*mean[n] = value[n]/n + mean[n-1]*(n-1)/n*

```
avg_vector=0; % It will be changed to a vector at first iteration
for k = TTs;   %TTs to plot
    folder=['TT',num2str(k)];   %TT folder

        for w = 1:4;
            file = ['TT' num2str(k) 'ch' num2str(w) '.mat'];
            count = 4*(k-1)+w;
            load(fullfile(folder,file));
            avg_vector = (1/count) * data(1,:) + ((count-1)/count) * avg_vector;
        end
end
```

Provided that the number of columns is not very large (in which case some precision may be lost to round-off errors) this will give the average. The only large vectors in memory are `avg_vector` and `data`

For a median, this more complicated as there is no incremental formula. You may have to add another loop over some subset of 1:N and do a selection.

```
filename=@(k,w) fullfile(['TT',num2str(k)],['TT' num2str(k) 'ch' num2str(w) '.mat']);
load(filename(1,1));
N=size(data,2);
median_all = zeros(1,N);

stride = 1e6;

for nn=1:stride:N
    rng = nn:min(N,nn+stride-1);
    MAT=zeros(128,length(rng));
    for k=TTs
        for w=1:4
            load(filename(k,w));
            MAT(4*(k-1)+w,:)=data(1,rng);
        end
    end
    median_all(1,rng) = median(MAT,1);
    clear MAT
end
```

There will be 128 million values at most in matrix MAT, so about 1GB if `data` is a 64-bit type (e.g. double). The downside is, file will have to be read several times. The balance is shifted from memory consumption to file I/O.

Comment: Thanks I'll be trying this out in a moment!

Comment: I've tested your solution for the average and avg_vector is in fact the same as the last file opened in the loop. No average was computed. Any idea on where the error might be?

Comment: There is a typo in the formula. it should be `avg_vector = (1/count) * data(1,:) + ((count-1)/count) * avg_vector(1,:);`. I'll edit the answer